# c# Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption 530

Tags: c#, windows, session, anonymous

I have read in many posts related to the same error but couldnt find a fix in C#.net windows application , as below code is using ftpFactory class.

Im getting 530 non anonymous session must use encryption in C#.net

it is failing near SENDCOMMAND("USER" " + remoteUser) and throwing "530 non anonymous session must use encryption" in the below code.

I'm changing this to make secured via PROTOCOL: FTPS (SSL/TLS) or the equivalent

```
clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(Dns.Resolve(remoteHost).AddressList[0], remotePort);


        try { clientSocket.Connect(ep); }

        catch (Exception) { throw new IOException("Couldn't connect to 
        remote server"); }

        readReply();
        if (retValue != 220)
        {
            close();
            throw new IOException(reply.Substring(4));
        }
        sendCommand("USER " + remoteUser);

        if (!(retValue == 331 || retValue == 230))
        {
            cleanup();
            throw new IOException(reply.Substring(4));
        }

        if (retValue != 230)
        {

            sendCommand("PASS " + remotePass);
            if (!(retValue == 230 || retValue == 202))
            {
                cleanup();
                throw new IOException(reply.Substring(4));
            }
        }

        logined = true;

        chdir(remotePath);
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: This is an http error message.  So you must send an http request.  You are using TCP which is the transport layer for http. See following code project : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL

Comment: saw the link, but clientsocket protocols doesnt use http , it only uses tcp. so do i need to change the entire code for this using CActiveSock?

Comment: Then why are you getting http error message 530?  You are using ftpFactory.  See "Differences from HTTP" at Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: stated with the code below

Comment: FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Comment: Should be using Default Credentials which is the user login credentials.